# not able to set up db for persistence data in superset

Tags: apache-superset

I installed superset thanks to the docker-compose file I found here https://github.com/apache/superset

I setup the db service like that

[image]

So first I launch db `docker-compos up db`, the container (named superset_db) is up and running

[image]

I retrieve the IP of superset_db then I put it in the superser_config.py file in line 170

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql+psycopg2://superset:superset@192.168.16.2:5432/superset'
```

192.168.16.2 is the Ip address of superset_db container

Then I launch the entire docker-compose file `docker-compose up --build` but installation failed, after a moment I had this error message

[image]

It seems that superset cannot reach superset_db, So I try to reach superset_db from my host with psql and I succeed :

[image]

Then I commented the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI in superser_config.py this time installation of superset was successfull and then inside the superset container I tried to reach superset db with psql command and it works

So why the parameter

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql+psycopg2://superset:superset@192.168.16.2:5432/superset

block the installation of superset ?
Any comment will be really appreciate

Thanks